# Is there a compelling reason to use DI with a module/class with no dependencies in a unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, language-agnostic, dependencies

Dependency injection can prove very useful for testing modules with dependencies. This isn't about those.

---

Say there is some concrete implementation,

```
public class DoesSomething : IDoesSomething 
{
    public int DoesImportant(int x, int y) 
    { 
        // perform some operation 
    }
}
```

that implements this,

```
public interface IDoesSomething
{
    int DoesImportant(int x, int y); 
}
```

In a unit test, you can obviously `new` up the test,

```
[TestMethod]
public void DoesSomething_CanDoDoesImportant()
{ 
    int expected = 42; 

    IDoesSomething foo = new DoesSomething(); 
    int actual = foo.DoesImportant(21, 2); 

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual); 
}
```

or use DI (Autofac here, but shouldn't matter for principle of question),

```
[TestMethod]
public void DoesSomething_CanDoDoesImportant()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<DoesSomething>().As<IDoesSomething>();
    var container = builder.Build();

    int expected = 42;
    IDoesSomething foo = container.Resolve<IDoesSomething>();
    int actual = foo.DoesImportant(21, 2);

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Given such a standalone module with no dependencies, is there a compelling reason to inject an `IDoesSomething` into the test? Or, is there a compelling reason to *not* inject an `IDoesSomething`?

Comment: Good catch :) - Yes, mocking / DI should be used with an implementation with dependencies. I'm asking specifically about standalone implementations.

Comment: You have it backwards. You want to make `DoSomething` implement an interface, so that *other classes* can be tested without failing because of `DoesImportant`. For your test, no, it's not needed at all, and could be plain bad design (if `new DoesSomething()` loaded from a factory, for example). Casting to the interface accomplishes nothing, but its not harmful (unless they have an interface-specific implementation). Your test is testing the implementation of `DoesSomething`, not of `IDoesSomething`. If you have multiple implementations, you should have tests for each concrete implementation.

Comment: @Rob This question is testing a *specific* Component (implementation, still implementing a Service); and not a [mockable] Service.

Comment: @user2864740 Not sure what you mean by that.. What component? If you mean `DoesSomething`, then yes, I understand. I elaborated on that in my comment

Comment: @Rob DoesSomething is a Component that implements the IDoesSomething Service.

Comment: @user2864740 Right, I understood that. And in my comment explained why the interface is irrelevant when testing a concrete implementation. Interfaces are to mock out the method when implementing other tests.

Comment: @Rob But the question is not about the interface.. so the comment confuses me.

Comment: @user2864740 It most definitely is... the question is specifically about interfaces..

Comment: @Rob The question (as I see it) is if there is a merit to use an IoC to load a *specific* DI-Component (with no dependencies), or to create an instance of the Component explicitly with `new`. *In both cases the same Interface/Service is adhered to.*

Comment: @user2864740 Right.. and that's what I discussed in my original comment :). "could be plain bad design (if new DoesSomething() loaded from a factory, for example)"

Comment: @Rob "You want to make DoSomething implement an interface.." but it *does*. Then there is "it's not needed at all", but the "it" seems ambiguous. The interface? (Which would conflict the previous?) or Injection of the *specific* Component? (Which is what the question is asking about, but why not? Or rather, what is lost/gained?)

Comment: Can you please clarify (i.e. with sample) where/how you'd "inject an `IDoesSomething` into the test"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *need* to use DI container for this test.

Here a reason why you *could* use DI container to resolve concrete class: all other tests use similar pattern to construct type via container and this one just happen to not require dependencies.

Unity sample:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DoesSomething_behaves_correctly()
{
     var expected = 42;
     var container = new UnityContainer();
     var foo = container.Resolve<DoesSomething>(); 
     int actual = foo.DoesImportant(21, 21); 

     Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual); 
}
```

Side benefit of this approach is that your test needs minimal changes when `DoesSomething` start having dependencies.

Comment: *Side benefit of this approach is that your test needs minimal changes when DoesSomething start having dependencies.* - I can get behind that sentiment for sure ... :)

Comment: I would still argue for using `IDoesSomething foo = ..` .. but this is what I think makes this question (maybe) interesting: Does this make a "compelling reason" to create the Component?

Answer (score 2):

Your tests should be written specifically against a *concrete* implementation.

Take this for example:

```
public void DoTestA()
{
    ObjectFactory.Set<IDoesSomething, DoesSomethingBadly>();

    var doesSomething = ObjectFactory.Get<IDoesSomething>();
    Assert.AreEqual(0, doesSomething.Add(1,1));
}

public void DoTestB()
{
    int expected = 42; 

    //This test is now *completely* dependent on DoTestA, and can give different results
    //depending on which test is run first. Further, we don't know
    //which implementation we're testing here. It's not immediately clear, even if
    //there's only one implementation.
    //As its a test, it should be very explicit in what it's testing.

    IDoesSomething foo = ObjectFactory.Get<IDoesSomething>(); 
    int actual = foo.DoesImportant(21, 21); 

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual); 
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class DoesSomething : IDoesSomething 
{
    public int Add(int x, int y) 
    { 
        return x+y;
    }
}

public class DoesSomethingBadly : IDoesSomething
{
    public int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x-y;
    }
}

public interface IDoesSomething
{
    int Add(int x, int y); 
}
```

In tests, directly referencing the class is definitely the way to go. We don't care that it's an interface, we only care about the concrete implementation.

`var foo = new DoesSomething();` is definitely the better option.

`IDoesSomething foo = new DoesSomething();` is not harmful, but it seems completely unneeded, as, again, we only care about the implementation, not the interface.

Comment: An IoC could very easily return a *specific* implementation - either during Setup registration or with `.Get<DoesSomething>()`, eg. Thus an IoC/DI can very much resolve to a concrete implementation. I don't think anyone is arguing against the first sentence.

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, but that just oozes bad design. Your tests are against a specific implementation. Why make it configurable for the whole set of tests in a Setup method? Why even use DI when you're absolutely testing against a particular implementation?

Comment: @user2864740 There is no point in retrieving instances from a container for a unit test, because a unit test, by definition, is scoped at a single unit of work within a single concrete class. Stated differently, the test  isn't dependent upon an abstraction; a DI container exists solely to fulfill dependencies on abstractions.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Now that's how the argument *should* be written.

Comment: I disagree that `var foo = ..` is better (back to my sentiments about the question *not* being about interfaces). I think that it is very much critical to test at interface contracts (unless testing [internal] methods which are not part of such a contract, but that is not the specific case shown). Not using an interface as the target will also fail for explicit interfaces, which I use quite a bit. Access through the polymorphic interface type has *nothing* to do with creation (and testing of) the concrete component itself.

Comment: @user2864740 In that case, you would have tests for both, no? If you want to test a method implemented explicitly for an interface, your test should indicate that and be clear just by reading it. In general, casting to the interface when are testing the concrete implementation in a test 1) Is not needed, and 2) Hides your intentions when you really *are* testing an interface-specific implementation.

Comment: @Rob Why have a test for both? That would be redundant. *It is interface type that is used as a DI Service* and so to test at that polymorphic type (which is independent of how the concrete type is created) - when appropriate - is the test that will more closely relate to actual usage. I don't understand what an "interface-specific implementation" is. The concrete Component type *is* the implementation; the polymorphic interface (which *is* the eventual Service) *is* the specification.

Comment: @user2864740 Why have a test for both? Because clearly both methods are used and are obviously different implementations if you went to the effort to write one explicitly for the interface. How is that redundant? If they're not both used, delete the unused method, and don't implement the other method explicitly against the interface. If you have different implementations of a method depending on what interface it's cast as, *all methods* should be tested, or removed if unused. You don't understand what an 'interface-specific implementation' is, but you said you use it 'quite a bit'. Huh?